# 使われていないCSS指定を自動で検出するには？

Tags: php, html, css

### 困りごと

php や html や css を書いて作業をしていたときのことです．

html の中で，レイアウトを変えようと思って，`<div class="hoge"></div>` を `table` に変更しました．

それに伴って CSS の中での

```css
div.hoge {
  text-align: center;
}
```

というような指定は不要になるわけです．

html や php のコードを編集して大幅に書き換えると，それに伴って不要なCSS指定がたくさん発生します．

それを自動で検出することはできないでしょうか？

### 試したこと

#### 開発者ツール

Chrome の開発者ツール上でカバレッジを使えば，そのページで使われていないCSSの指定を洗い出すことができます．

とても有効なのですが，そのページしか調べることができません．フォルダ全体で調べたいのですが，書いているのが php なので難しそうだと感じています．

#### 検索する

フォルダ内で検索するというやり方です．堅実なやり方ではありますが，CSS のすべての指定について繰り返さないといけないので，CSS が長大だとかなり面倒ではないかと思います．

### 質問

私はテキストエディタとして VSCode を使用しています．

VSCode の適当な拡張機能で実現できないでしょうか？

VSCode を使わない方法でも構いません．

Comment: 動的なページでCSSのカバレッジはそもそもCSSとHTMLの対応が三者三葉で単純に行いにくい部分があり、モジュール志向のCSSやscoped CSSなどといったものが好まれる理由でもありますが、Chromeの開発者ツールのようにカバレッジをとる手段もいくつかあるはずです。たとえば、Puppeteerでコードからブラウザを操作しながら複数ページのカバレッジをとることが可能なようです。 [Puppeteerで不要なCSSを消す - Cybozu Inside Out | サイボウズエンジニアのブログ](https://blog.cybozu.io/entry/2019/08/20/170000)

Comment: ユースケースによってはよさそう [PurgeCSS - Remove unused CSS | PurgeCSS](https://purgecss.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PurgeCSSというツールで使われていないCSSを除外することができそうです。
[PurgeCSS - Remove unused CSS | PurgeCSS](https://purgecss.com/)
デモ動画：[How to Scan and Remove Unused CSS Properties | PurgeCSS Tutorial - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3WQoON6Vfc)